# Python: numpy.dot / numpy.tensordot for multidimensional arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, backpropagation, tensordot

I'm optimising my implementation of the back-propagation algorithm to train a neural network. One of the aspects I'm working on is performing the matrix operations on the set of datapoints (input/output vector) as a batch process optimised by the numpy library instead of looping through every datapoint.

In my original algorithm I did the following:

```
for datapoint in datapoints:
  A = ... (created out of datapoint info)
  B = ... (created out of datapoint info)

  C = np.dot(A,B.transpose())
____________________

A: (7,1) numpy array
B: (6,1) numpy array
C: (7,6) numpy array
```

I then expanded said matrices to tensors, where the first shape index would refer to the dataset. If I have 3 datasets (for simplicity purposes), the matrices would look like this:

```
A: (3,7,1) numpy array
B: (3,6,1) numpy array
C: (3,7,6) numpy array
```

**Using ONLY np.tensordot or other numpy manipulations, how do I generate C?**

I assume the answer would look something like this:

```
C = np.tensordot(A.[some manipulation], B.[some manipulation], axes = (...))
```

(This is a part of a much more complex application, and the way I'm structuring things is not flexible anymore. If I find no solution I will only loop through the datasets and perform the multiplication for each dataset)

Comment: If the posted solution worked for you, please consider accepting. More info - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use [`np.einsum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
c = np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijl',a,b)
```

Since the last axes are singleton, you might be better off with sliced arrays -

```
c = np.einsum('ij,il->ijl',a[...,0],b[...,0])
```

With [`np.matmul/@-operator`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) -

```
c = a@b.swapaxes(1,2)
```

Comment: Hi Divakar thanks a lot! That worked perfect for me. Exactly what i was looking for. I ended up using the first variant of your answer. Also I'm new to stackoverflow (posting questions), so I'm not sure how to "accept" your answer (I already upvoted it). Edit: Found the "accept" button :)