# Python Backpropagation: Gradient becomes increasingly small for increasing batch size

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

I'm training a neural network of the following dimensions:
784 (input layer)
45 (hidden layer)
16 (output layer)

for the classification of digits and some mathematical symbols (0-9,+,-,*,/,[,]), using backpropagation (stochastic gradient descent)

I'm doing some testing when it comes to the choice of mini-batch size and found out the following problems:

**1. Using a mini-batch size of 20 datapoints the backpropagation algorithm "seems" to work, but even after training it on 50+ epochs, the accuracy seems only to fluctuate and get worse (Figure 1)**

[image: Epoch vs Accuracy 1 = 100%]

**2 .Using a mini-batch size of 2000 datapoints the weight-gradients are so small that they don't really change the actual weights after updating them**

[image]

Below i'm posting the relevant code of the Class I'm using to train the Neural Network Object. Although not everything is visible, the names are quite self-explanatory.

Some relevant data:

1. The training dataset is ~200k datapoints (tuple of 28x28 numpy array and the corresponding symbol)
2. The validation dataset is ~50k datapoints
3. The algorithm uses MSE as a cost function
4. I'm using the backpropagation algorithm as of the following formulas:

[image: Backpropagation algorithm]

5. IMPORTANT: To make the backpropagation calculation more efficient I performed calculations as batch tensor operations where the corresponding gradients are in tensors where the first axis corresponds to the dataset index and the rest act as normal matrices/vectors. More to that on a previous question:
   [Python: numpy.dot / numpy.tensordot for multidimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62349905/python-numpy-dot-numpy-tensordot-for-multidimensional-arrays?noredirect=1#comment110317536_62349905)

Example (mini-batch size: 20)

Activation at the final layer:
for one data set is: (16x1)
for batch backpropagation is: (20x16x1)

Gradient to Weight at the last layer:
for one data set is: (16x45)
for batch backpropagation is: (20x16x45)

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class NeuralNetworkTrainer:
  def __init__(self, neuralNetwork,validator):
    self.network = neuralNetwork # Uses the neural network object which contains weights, bias' as a list of numpy arrays for each layer (the first element being 'None' to be consistent with indexes), as well as activations and layer sizes
    self.eta = 0
    self.dataSet = [] # Another class loads the dataset here (tuples of inputs, 2D-numpy arrays of the image and outputs, the corresponding symbol)
   
    self.initializeWeightsBias()
    self.validator = validator # validator object
    self.validationAccuracy = [] # list of accuracies per epoch
    
  def initializeWeightsBias(self): #gradients initialization
    self.gradientToBias = [None]*len(self.network.layers)
    self.gradientToWeights = [None]*len(self.network.layers)

  def train(self,epochs,miniBatchSize,eta): #train algorithm
    self.eta = eta
    for i in range(0,epochs):
      self.shuffleData()
      for j in range(0,len(self.dataSet)//miniBatchSize):
        self.batchBackPropagation(self.createMiniBatch(miniBatchSize,j))
        self.update()

      correctOutputs, dataSetLength = self.validator.validate()
      self.validationAccuracy.append(round(correctOutputs/dataSetLength,4))
    
    return self.network

# ***************************
# BACKPROPAGATION ALGORITHM

  def batchBackPropagation(self,inputOutputBatch):
    self.initializeWeightsBias()

    activations = [None]*len(self.network.activations)
    for i in range(0,len(activations)): #Initialize activations
      activations[i] = np.empty((len(inputOutputBatch),self.network.activations[i].shape[0],self.network.activations[i].shape[1]))
    
    output = np.empty((len(inputOutputBatch),self.network.activations[-1].shape[0],self.network.activations[-1].shape[1])) #correct formatting of output vector out of the symbol (vector with 0's and a 1 in the corresponding output)
    for i in range(0,len(inputOutputBatch)):
      inputVector, outputVector = self.vectorizeInputOuput(inputOutputBatch[i])
      self.network.loadInput(inputVector)
      self.network.activate() #feedforward of input through the network with current weights/bias
      output[i] = outputVector
      for l in range(1,len(activations)): #creation of activation tensor as explained before
        activations[l][i] = self.network.activations[l]
    
    self.gradientToBias[-1] =(activations[-1]-output)*(activations[-1]-np.square(activations[-1])) #calculation of gradientBias for last layer for all the minibatches as a 3D tensor calculation (see algorithm image)
    for i in range(2,len(self.network.layers)):
      self.gradientToBias[-i] = np.tensordot(self.gradientToBias[-i+1],self.network.weights[-i+1],axes= ((1),(0))).transpose(0,2,1)*(activations[-i]-np.square(activations[-i])) #calculation of the rest of the gradientToBias for the rest of the layers as a 3D tensor calculation the first index being the index of the dataset in that minibatch (according to algorithm image)
    for i in range(1,len(self.network.layers)):
      self.gradientToWeights[i] = np.einsum('ijk,ilm->ijl',self.gradientToBias[i],activations[i-1])
    return self.network # analogous 3D tensor calculation of gradientToWeights for each dataset in the minibatch inside every layer of the 3D tensor

# *****************************

  def update(self): #reduction of gradients of each dataset to one final gradient to each parameter by summing over axis=0)
    for i in range(1,len(self.network.layers)):
      self.network.weights[i] -= self.eta*np.sum(self.gradientToWeights[i],axis =0)
      self.network.bias[i] -= self.eta*np.sum(self.gradientToBias[i], axis = 0)
    return self.network

  def shuffleData(self): #self explanatory
    rd.shuffle(self.dataSet)
    return self.network 

  def createMiniBatch(self, miniBatchSize, index): #self explanatory
    return self.dataSet[index*miniBatchSize:(index+1)*miniBatchSize] 

  def mapOutputToVector(self,output): #self explanatory
      outputVector = np.zeros((len(self.network.outputMap),1))
      outputVector[self.network.outputMap.index(output)] = 1
      return outputVector

  def vectorizeInputOuput(self,inputOutputData): #selfexplanatory
    return inputOutputData.input.flatten().reshape((-1,1)), self.mapOutputToVector(inputOutputData.output)
```

**GREATLY appreciate any help!**

Comment: One thing to try is lower your hidden layers. Your architecture is maybe too larger for this simple of a problem. Also, add some dropout into the mix as well to help make the model more generalized.  This looks like it is learning too specific features which is why it fluctuates.  2000 is normally too large a batch size try this range [16:526] Those are some of the literature best options. For your small dataset I would stick to 32 or 64.

Comment: There’s only one hidden layer. Do you mean reducing its size? Thanks!

Comment: I see I read it wrong ' 45 (hidden layer)' I would try this 784->64->32->16 This set up worked well for a pytorch model I built

Comment: The examples I've seen of people using the MNIST library to recognise handwritten digits are usually with one hidden layer. Are you sure putting two layers and increasing the amount of parameters by ca. 50% is not over-complicating things only for 6 more characters?

Comment: @MichelH. Use *cross-entropy loss* as cost function, MSE does not work well for classification problems. For activation function, use *relu* or *tanh* for the hidden layers and *softmax* for the output layer. Also use a for loop and try training with different values of `eta`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all too large of a mini-batch size usually leads to a lower accuracy.

The problem you are facing in the first figure is over fitting so you need to reduce the number of epochs.

As for the second figure, you have 200,000 samples and a batch size of 2000 then the epoch should contain 200,000 / 2000 = 100 steps which considered as small number of steps in your gradient per epoch

In general you need to choose the right number for both number of epochs and batch size to get the best result. Maybe 1000 steps in the epoch and don't train too much epochs to avoid overfitting

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I'm not fully convinced by your answer. Why does a larger mini-batch size decrease accuracy? We create mini-batches in the first place because of memory issues. With no memory constraints, we would "chose" the mini-batch to be the full training set, and just iterate it over the epochs. Also, there's no way I'm overfitting a 200k dataset after 20 epochs with a neural network that has around 35k parameters. The big questions is why do the weight-gradients become so small? Am i doing everything right with the matrix initialization? Am I manipulating the nump arrays incorrectly?

Comment: this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/tradeoff-batch-size-vs-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neural-network) discus the effect of mini-batch size take a look. As for the code itself the easiest thing to do is to build another neural network using keras or tensorflow with the same hyper parameters and compare the results. (I can't see any thing wrong in the code btw). But i still believe that it can be an overfitting the distribution of the dataset play a role also no only the number of the samples